# write() and read() do not work on stdio instead of fifo

Tags: c, fifo

I have a problem related to fifos and the `write()` and `read()` functions. I do create the fifo through the `mkfifo()` function then I use `fork()` to generate two processes: the first one opens and writes on the fifo through write(); the other opens and reads through read().
My problem is that `write()` writes on the stdout and `read()` waits for me to write something on the stdin and to press Enter, just like a `scanf()`, thus not using the fifo. I really don't know what to do anymore, I have tried anything and haven't found any related problem on the internet so far. 
I am using gcc compiler and Xubuntu 15.10.

**Process generator**

```
int main (void) {

    int f = mkfifo("try", S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (f < 0)
        printf("mkfifo went fine\n");
    else
        printf("mkfifo went wrong\n");
    pid_t fo = fork();
    switch (fo) {
    case -1:
        printf("err\n");
    case 0:
        execlp("prova_fifo2", "prova_fifo2", NULL);
    default:
        execlp("prova_fifo", "prova_fifo", NULL);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

**Writer (aka prova_fifo)**

```
int main (void) {

    int fd;
    if (fd = open("try", O_WRONLY) == -1)
        printf("Error opening FIFO\n");

    char buf[6];
    sprintf(buf, "hello");
    int writer = write(fd, buf, strlen(buf));
    printf("%d", writer);
    return (0);
}
```

**Reader (aka prova_fifo2)**

```
int main (void) {

    int fd;
    if (fd = open("try", O_RDONLY) ==-1)
    printf("Errore in apertura FIFO\n");

    char buf[6];
    read(fd,&buf, strlen(buf)); //tried removing the "&", didn't work
    printf("READ: %s", buf);
    return (0); 
}
```

**NOTE** I am including all the necessary libraries, the code compiles and runs. My only problem is the one mentioned above.

Comment: `read(fd,&buf, strlen(buf));` this buff is uninntialised, aand strlen() can do terrible things if it does not find a 0. also: read() *could* read more than the actual size into the small buffer

Comment: regarding the code block beginning with `if (f < 0)`  1) if 'f' is less than 0 then the call to mkfifo() failed.  In that case, call: `perror( mkfifo failed" ) ; exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`.  because if the function fails, there is no reason to continue in the code and the call to `perror()` will output what the system thinks the problem was.

Comment: when the call to `execlp()` fails, the call will return. so each call to `execlp()` should be followed by something like: `perror( "execlp failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: this line: `read(fd,&buf, strlen(buf));` should be: `ssize_t bytesread = read(fd,buf, sizeof(buf));  buf[bytesread] = '\0';`

Comment: this line: `printf("Error opening FIFO\n");` should be: `perror("Error opening FIFO\n"); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  as the code should not continue, trying to read from a file that it failed to open.    Similar considerations apply to the line: `printf("Errore in apertura FIFO\n");`

Comment: the reader and writer code seems to be missing `#include <stdio.h> #include <unistd.h>`   The writer code seems to be missing: `#include <string.h>`

Comment: the process generator seems to be missing: `#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>`

Comment: these lines: `case -1:
        printf("err\n");` has the problem that it will 'fall through' to the next case.  similar considerations exist for the other two cases if the call to execlp() fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) issue, the expression `fd=open("try", O_WRONLY )==-1` is equivalent to `fd=(open("try", O_WRONLY )==-1)` which is most definitely not what you want, as that will assign the result of `open(...)==-1` to `fd` which will be false (i.e. `0` which is the file descriptor for standard *input*) if the file can be found, and `1` if the file *can not* be found.

You need to do `(fd=open("try", O_WRONLY ))==-1`.

Comment: Thanks!! This fixed it! It was so damn simple!

Answer (score 1):

You can't sensibly call `strlen()` on an uninitialized `char` array. You should do:

```
read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
```

instead.

Note that `read()` won't zero-terminate your array, and `printf()` expects to receive such a thing for `%s`, so you may want to change the whole thing to:

```
char buf[7] = {0};
if ( read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1) > 0 ) {
    printf("READ: %s\n", buf);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the code i posted was just a sample of the real, "huge" code i am developing.